# Extending a class vs. adding boolean parameter

Tags: java, coding-style

When writing a program in Java, if I have a special case of an object that needs to be treated differently by the main class but that does not require any additional methods, is it better to add a boolean parameter to the constructor of the object such as isSpecial and to check whether the object is special in the main class or to create a new object that extends the original?

Example:

I have a Cat class. If a cat has whiskers, I want to print "This cat has whiskers!" in the Main class.

Would it be better to have a WhiskerCat class or to simply add a boolean parameter to the Cat constructor such as hasWhiskers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the boolean parameter. You don't want to end up with an excess of classes that do roughly the same thing. For example, in the Cat class, the default value for hasWhiskers should be false, and remain false if they don't call the constructor that explicitly requires them to specify it. Then you can have a `hasWhiskers()` method that returns this boolean attribute.

In general, only extend a class if the new class has additional functionality (additional methods etc) that cannot simply be tacked on to the original.

Comment: Just wondering: Let's say you have 4 booleans associated with the Cat class. Would you write 16 different constructors for all the possible combinations of parameters that you use? My guess would be that you only write ones that would be frequently used.

Comment: You could choose to write 16 different constructors (assuming that it is okay for your class to have any number of the booleans set by the user and have any number not set by the user) but typically you would only write constructors for the combinations that would only be frequently used. Or, for that matter, you could have one constructor that requires the users to specify everything, and the user could just write 'false' for all the boolean parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of responsibilities: which class is doing what?
Your "main" class should not probably be aware of the internals of the "Cat" class.

In your case that means the implementation of the Cat class would probably need to be adjusted to either have a new interface that the main class could use to print that message.

Then the Cat class itself could either have that boolean, a (list of) component that make up the cat or you could go the inheritance way. This will most likely depend on the real problem: is there many more variations? is that really the only difference? are you taking a class/exam? (in the last case it might be more useful to just apply the way you've been taught).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems are about **design patterns** instead of **coding style**.

In general,if you want to add some new features in a class.

First,you should ask yourself is it a interface or a property?If it is a property,then there are two ways to tackle it.

Way 1:**subclass** as you metioned

Way 2:you should use **delegate** (i.e. add a hairclass to consider whether it is a long hair cat
      or it is short hair cat.)

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, is adding a boolean the only way to recognize if the object is special? For sure there must be other characteristics that make it special?

Anyway, it's not the responsibility of the main class to know if it is. Leave what should be printed to the Cat class, not on the Main class.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it depends on how special that attribute is.

If we consider another example:

cars...
The attribute 'sunroof' or 'navi' is quite common and has no special requirement to the car and may be part of the base class.
But a siren and flash light are quite uncommon and would be better fit if they are attributes of another extended class.